# Which Office 365 Product for Product/Service Documentation?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-onenote

The company I work for uses Office 365 for just about everything. I'm trying to figure out which Office 365 app I should use for storing my department's documentation and help files. I need to be able to limit read and write access to this documentation to only my team. It also needs to be easily searched. I would prefer it to be easily accessed via a web browser too and minimize the need for desktop and mobile apps to edit or access content.

I see inside of the Teams app, there is a Wiki tab. At first glance it seems too simple. I don't see any type of search capability.

It appears another option is OneNote. This may be more robust then we need. I will be honest. I haven't really done much research on this. I'm concerned about web based access with this product.

I'm also guessing Sharepoint may be a possibility. Again, no research yet, just going off my very limited knowledge of the software.

Can anyone give their two cents?

Answer (score 0):

We keep our dev docs on a Sharepoint wiki for our internal knowledge base type stuff.  It is searchable.

Actual specs for various projects are a mixup of where they are.  Sometimes in our Jira ticketing, sometimes in our old ticketing system (IBM Jazz), sometimes on a shared drive on a file server, sometimes in Sharepoint, sometimes in OneDrive and shared out.  Many times in more than one of these, sometimes different versions with different changed-on dates, with different changes.